# What does "Migrating a Django application" mean?

Tags: database, django, migration, django-south

I kept thinking a lot about the meaning of `migrating a Django app` the last few days and heard about migrating Django apps with [django-south](http://south.aeracode.org/). Maybe it's just the lack of sufficient English skills (as English is not my native language) or this is one of the things you confront in a programmer's life which are so simple, that it takes a genius to understand them (at first).

I've read the translation of 'migrate' in my native language, read the definition of `migration` on Wikipedia and read ["the idea](http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/About#TheIdea)" of django-south, citing:

> With South, you install it and then
>   give one or more of your apps some
>   migrations (either writing them by
>   hand, or autogenerating them from your
>   model definitions). When you syncdb,
>   you'll only sync apps that don't have
>   migrations (things like
>   django.contrib.auth, for example,
>   which have a fixed schema), and then
>   when you run ./manage.py migrate,
>   South kicks in and does the
>   migrations. Intelligently.

This is confusing and I still don't understand the whole thing behind "migration of django applications" or "migration in general". I'd understand if I'd know how to interpret the word `migration`

**You get the point, I hope.**

Have patience with me, but I'd really like to know. So maybe one of you could explain me, please.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When it comes to talking about South and Django, a migration refers to changing the database schema.

The `syncdb` command that is built into Django cannot automatically change schema for you without deleting everything first, which is why things like South and dmigrations have come about.

So, essentially a migration is a way to alter your database schema while keeping your data intact.

From the [dmigrations page](http://code.google.com/p/dmigrations/):

> With dmigrations, every change to your
>   database (including the creation of
>   your initial tables) is bundled up in
>   a migration. Migrations are Python
>   files that live in a migrations
>   directory. They can be applied and
>   un-applied (reverted) in sequence.

Comment: "So, essentially a migration is a way to alter your database schema while keeping your data intact." This absolutely makes sense now. Thanks, TM.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate typically refers to moving an application from one location to another. This translation can happen either via a physical movement. (Such as moving from one server to another), or as a more logical movement. (Such as from C# to F#)

Given that only one technology is mentioned. It is likely primarily a physical movement application with a slight logical movement of the database side.

To summarize what the application does. It likely simply exports all of your configuration and data to a file structure, which can then be reintegrated into your database on the new server.