# What does migrate mean in django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm currently learning Django using python. I'm using the Django website as my reference and there is one line of code that I am supposed to enter " python manage.py migrate'. I'm wondering what does migrate means and what does it do?

Thank You!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "Migrating a Django application" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949901/what-does-migrating-a-django-application-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, it syncs changes you make to the Database.  When you are just starting out on a project, you will need to enter "python manage.py migrate" to initially create the DB.  Later, when you add models and update them, you will need to push these changes to your DB and "python manage.py migrate" will do the trick.  Although you will need to enter "python manage.py makemigrations" first to get ready for the DB changes.